# discovered untitest class triangle warning

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

vscode 1.52.1 on mac big sur with the python extension. My unittests are discovered and run just fine, however, I see this icon next to the unittest class but not the test methods in the class. It is a triangle with an (!) in it, which is generally a warning symbol if some kind, Can anyone shed light on to what it is telling me? There is no tool-tip or hover text. Thanks!

[image: warning symbol]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During testing, when there are methods that succeed in the test and also methods that fail in the test class, the test class tests all test methods in the class, and it displays warning signs. After we fix the failed test method and click "`Run Test`" again, the warning next to the test class will disappear.

[image]

Reference: [Testing in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_a-little-background-on-unit-testing).

Comment: Thanks! The animated gif was above and beyond :-)